# .jrxml to .jasper compile error field not found exception

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Hi i'm new to jasper report.i'm using ireport for designing report.
I have created a simple report design, which have 2 fields name,addr.

```
public class R {
     private String name;
      private String addr;

      public R(String name, String addr) {
       super();
       this.name = name;
       this.addr = addr;
      }
      public String getName() {
       return name;
      }
      public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
      }
      public String getAddr() {
       return addr;
      }
      public void setAddr(String addr) {
       this.addr = addr;
      }
}
```

**.jrxml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="R" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="4fd2f78e-344d-4371-ba1e-f86c2a81ef75">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="296" y="41" width="228" height="20" uuid="19aa39a0-45cf-4b36-b327-25b640f81d8a"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Address]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="36" y="41" width="215" height="20" uuid="baba8372-2215-439d-8b20-fd4ab054bbe5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="296" y="0" width="228" height="20" uuid="c4de17e6-e5bc-4454-b38e-cc50acf18f0b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{addr}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="36" y="0" width="215" height="20" uuid="8283d8b6-a288-48ec-bd4a-36c2875f5cff"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Here i'm using array list as a data source.
When i click compile button on i report it shows error that

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid :       1. Field not found : addr      2. Field not found : name
```

**java code**

```
public void runReport(String fileName, String outFileName) throws JRException 
     {

       List<R> list = new ArrayList<R>();

       Map parameters = new HashMap();
       list.add(new R("a1" ,"a2"));
       list.add(new R("b1" ,"b2"));
       list.add(new R("c1" ,"c2"));

       JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport( fileName, parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
                JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
                exporter.setParameter(
                JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,outFileName);
                exporter.setParameter(
                JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, outFileName);
                print = null;
                exporter = null;

        }
```

Comment: You have not defined any fields in your JRXML. Isn't that necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to your jrxml field:

```
<field name="addr" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[addr]]></fieldDescription></field>
```

You can do it by clicking on "fields" and selecting "create field".